# IndexOutOfBoundsException Instead of Ending Loop

Tags: java, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

Why does

```
int row = 1;
// multiArray[col].length = 6

while(multiArray[col][row] > 1 && row < multiArray[col].length) {
    sum += multiArray[col][row];
    row++;
}
```

Return an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

I thought that if row became 6, the while loop just wouldn't run, instead of returning an error.

Comment: need to switch your condition.

Comment: Literally just figured it out, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&&` operator is a [short-circuit operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).  That means that if it can tell the results from the left operand, then it won't evaluate the right side.

Switch the order of operands, so the in-bounds check comes first, and if it fails, the array value check won't occur, which would throw the exception if evaluated.

```
while(row < multiArray[col].length && multiArray[col][row] > 1) {
```